# Understanding Assignment Solution in Agda

Tags: functional-programming, agda, bottom-type

Consider the following extracted piece of code for proving the "Unicity of Typing" for variable in Agda:

```
unicity : ∀ {Γ₁ Γ₂ e τ₁ τ₂} →  (Γ₁ ⊢ e ∷ τ₁) → (Γ₂ ⊢ e ∷ τ₂) → (Γ₁ ≈ Γ₂) → (τ₁ ∼ τ₂)
unicity   (VarT here) (VarT here) (_ , ( τ∼ , _ ))   = τ∼ 
unicity (VarT here) (VarT (ski`p {α = α} lk2)) (s≡s' , ( _ , _ )) = ⊥-elim (toWitnessFalse α (toWitness` s≡s'))
unicity (VarT (skip {α = α} lk1)) (VarT here) (s'≡s , ( _ , _ )) = ⊥-elim (toWitnessFalse α (toWitness s'≡s))
unicity (VarT (skip lk1)) (VarT (skip lk2)) (_ ,( _ , Γ≈ ))     = unicity (VarT lk1) (VarT lk2) Γ≈
```

I need an explanation on the working of `⊥-elim` , `toWitnessFalse` and  `toWitness`. Also, what do the expressions `⊤` and `⊥` mean/stand for?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained file? As for [⊥ and ⊥-elim](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Empty.html#1), [⊤](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Unit.html#1) and [toWitness and toWitnessFalse](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Nullary.Decidable.html#1055) you can have a look at the documentation of the standard library.

Comment: @gallais Could you plz elaborate these? like how do they work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`⊥`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Empty.html) is the empty type, so (in a total, consistent language) you can never construct a value of type `⊥`. But this [also means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) that any proposition you can think of, follows from `⊥`. This is what `⊥-elim` witnesses:

```
⊥-elim : ∀ {w} {Whatever : Set w} → ⊥ → Whatever
```

This is very useful in practice because you might be writing proofs under some assumption, and some of those assumptions might be `⊥`, or they might be negative statements (`A → ⊥` for some `A`) and you can prove the `A` as well, etc. Then, what you find out is effectively that you don't have to care about that particular branch anymore, since it is impossible; but then, just because you don't care, you still have to formally satisfy the result type somehow. This is what `⊥-elim` gives you.

[`toWitness`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Nullary.Decidable.html#1055)'s type and related definitions are as follows:

```
T : Bool → Set
T true  = ⊤
T false = ⊥

⌊_⌋ : ∀ {p} {P : Set p} → Dec P → Bool
⌊ yes _ ⌋ = true
⌊ no  _ ⌋ = false

True : ∀ {p} {P : Set p} → Dec P → Set
True Q = T ⌊ Q ⌋

toWitness : ∀ {p} {P : Set p} {Q : Dec P} → True Q → P
```

Given a `Q : Dec P`, `True Q` is either `⊤` (if `Q = yes _`) or `⊥` (if `Q = no _`). The only way to call `toWitness`, then, is to have `Q` say that `P` is true and pass the trivial unit constructor `tt : ⊤`; the only other possibility would be to have `Q` say that `P` is false, and pass as an argument a `⊥` but as we've seen, that's not possible. In summary, `toWitness` says that if `Q` tells us the decision that `P` holds, then we can get a proof of `P` from `Q`.

[`toWitnessFalse`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Nullary.Decidable.html#1354) is exactly the same with the roles reversed: if `Q` tells us the decision that `P` doesn't hold, then we can get a proof of `¬ P` from `Q`.